# ASP.NET MVC выпадающий список с помощью jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Есть выпадающий список

```
<select id="sort_order"
                <option>select</option>
                <option value="Price">Price</option>
                <option value="Rating">Rating</option>
</select>
```

Необходимо при выборе элемента списка вызвать метод "List" контроллера "Product" и в качестве параметра передать sortOrder="Price" или sortOrder="Rating" соответственно.

Можно ли реализовать подобное средствами только ASP.NET MVC?

Подскажите,пожалуйста, скрипт jQuery с описанной функциональностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<select id="sort_order" onchange="CallActionList($(this).val()); return false;"
                <option>select</option>
                <option value="Price">Price</option>
                <option value="Rating">Rating</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
function CallActionList(sortOrder){
     $.post('@Url.Action("List", "Product")', { sortOrder: sortOrder }, function(response){
         //тут необходимые действия с возвращаемым результатом
    }

}
```